# Pry keeps breaking although I removed binding.pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry

Using gem 'pry-rails'. I run `bundle exec rails c production` and executed `gem-cd mongoid`. Then opened storage_options.rb by running `edit lib/mongoid/sessions/storage_options.rb`. I put a breakpoint (binding.pry) in some line and close the file. I made some test and debugged ok. When I came back and got rid of the breakpoint, Pry will keep stopping at the same point although `binding.pry` is not there anymore (at least what I see on the console) and when I edit the file:

Before:

```
From: /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/sessions/storage_options.rb @ line 134 Mongoid::Sessions::StorageOptions::ClassMethods#__evaluate__:

    129:         # @return [ Symbol ] The value as a symbol.
    130:         #
    131:         # @since 3.1.0
    132:         def __evaluate__(name)
    133:           binding.pry
 => 134:           return nil unless name
    135:           name.respond_to?(:call) ? name.call.to_sym : name.to_sym
    136:         end
    137:       end
    138:     end
    139:   end
    140: end

[1] pry(User)>
```

After:

```
From: /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/sessions/storage_options.rb @ line 134 Mongoid::Sessions::StorageOptions::ClassMethods#__evaluate__:
    129:         # @return [ Symbol ] The value as a symbol.
    130:         #
    131:         # @since 3.1.0
    132:         def __evaluate__(name)
    133:           return nil unless name
 => 134:           name.respond_to?(:call) ? name.call.to_sym : name.to_sym
    135:         end
    136:       end
    137:     end
    138:   end
    139: end

[1] pry(User)>
```

Why does this happen? How can I "delete" the breakpoint?

Comment: we normally pry in` development` and` test ` env only.  I think restarting the console/server have to fix this issue. Make sure that you had writing access to that file. :)

Comment: @cba_bhusal thanks, but if I didn't had write access it wouldn't let me stick binding.pry in the first place, right? However, I have write access. Also, restarting the console doesn't fix this. I had that situation before, where I own a file, I insert binding.pry, and it doesn't go away until I restart. However, this seems to be different. It looks like pry doesn't get cleared when you restart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart your server, otherwise Ruby would not reload the file and would not see your changes.

Comment: I already restarted by exiting and running `bundle exec rails c production` again.